# How do we add functions in existing Django views?

Tags: python, django

This is my current views.py. In this case, how could I add reverse_sentence function as another view?

```
class SentenceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Sentence.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SentenceSerializer


def reverse_sentence(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sentence = Sentence.objects.all.values('content')
        reversed_words = ' '.join(reversed(sentence.split()))
        response_data = {'reversed_sentence': reversed_words}
        return JsonResponse(response_data)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid request method. Must use POST.'})
```

and when I use `router.register(r'reverse_sentence', views.reverse_sentence, basename='reverse_sentence')` in urls.py, how come it shows `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `router.register` is only used to add a new view set class, which must derive from `ModelViewSet`.  You just want to add another pattern to your `urlpatterns`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another view like this

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def reverse_sentence(request):
    """Your working here"""
    sentence = Sentence.objects.all.values('content')
    reversed_words = ' '.join(reversed(sentence.split()))
    response_data = {'reversed_sentence': reversed_words}
    return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

And in URLs, register your URL like this.

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

re_path(r'^reverse-sentence/$',
                 views.reverse_sentence),
```

Another approach is you can make another class with ModelViewSet or APIView and write your function inside that class